# AWS S3 Eventual Consistency: Why does a bucket list return a key, but a head request None

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, consistency, eventual-consistency

I am reading the AWS documentation, and have a question regarding the behavior of my application.

1. I make a `get_key` request to a nonexistent key.
2. Then I put that object.
3. Then I make another `get_key` request to the same key.

Now, the documentation explains why I might get None at step 3: *"The caveat is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides eventual consistency for read-after-write."* (from the docs)

What I am concerned about, is why a `list` call on my bucket after step 2, lists the key (even if at step 3 I still get a `None` for this same key).

```
for k in bucket.list(some_path):
    key = k.get_key(k.name)
```

Most of these work, but randomly some will return None.
Shouldn't it be the case that the list returns the `key` only if it is available ? And how could I make sure I eventually get the value (is there a notification system whereby I'm notified when step 3 will actually return my object, or could a timed-out retry work-> say, wait a couple of seconds and try again?)

Comment: Please post some sample code

Comment: It's a distributed system. Because you have issued a HEAD or GET prior to a PUT of the object, you no longer have read after write consistency. Your LIST request may hit one server that sees the object while your subsequent GET hits a server that does not yet see the object. No, there is no notification of when the PUT is fully consistent in this case. Don't issue a HEAD or GET in advance if you need read after write consistency. One technique is to use UUIDs for new objects, or maintain an index in DynamoDB or equivalent.

Comment: @jarmod that's really the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, could be you get nothing ( 404 ) . And as I know Amazon is not defining a maximum time for "S3 provides eventual consistency for read-after-write" . What you know for sure is after step 2 the file is saved in the AWS bucket. If you have versioning enabled on the bucket the file will be there as a version even another write is overwriting your file.
 I think you have 2 options ,

1. Option A: build a caching mechanism and keep the file in cache  until you get 200 for the request. Cache could be a simple folder .
2. Option B: in STEP 3 --> loop till you get the 200 ( add a delay inside the loop ). You know this will happen the problem is sometimes this could be longer, usually for normal size file this is fast.
3. Option C: consider finishing STEP 2 only after you get the 200.

I save sometimes huge database backups ( 500GB-1TB) to s3 and after the download is done ( takes sometimes hours ) there is a lag of 5-60 sec till I GET the 200 ( could by my data-center network is guilty too ) . The delay on the S3 web console page is even longer, sometimes I am able to filter for this file only after 5 min . For small size files I never detected delays.